# Integral test on $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)\ln^2(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to investigate if the following series is convergence or divergence 
**$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)\ln^2(n+1)}$**

I applied the integral test and reached this result  $\frac{1}{\ln 2}$ and hence the series is convergent, but I'm not sure of the result. Any help ??

Comment: You have a sign error, $$\int_2^\infty \frac{dt}{t(\log t)^2} = \int_{\log 2}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} = \left[-\frac1x\right]_{\log 2}^\infty = -\left(0-\frac{1}{\log 2}\right) = \frac{1}{\log 2}.$$

Comment: aha I'm sorry, you are right, but I think it stills convergence. doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Yes, since the integral is finite, the sum is convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the test is applied correctly and the series converges.

In fact, you can show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)\ln^\alpha (n+1)}$ converges if and only if $\alpha>1$.

One step further, the series $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n\ln^a(\ln n)}$ converges also if and only if $\alpha>1$. Etc.